# Finding the complex eigenvectors in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\begin{bmatrix}5 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ act on $\mathbb{C}^2$. Find the eigenvalues and a basis for each eigenspace in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

[image]

I was following along until the solution chose $x_2=2$. Since $x_1=(1+i)x_2$ and we are setting $x_1=1+i$, wouldn't it only make sense to set $x_2=1$?

Comment: You are right. It seems that there is a typo in the proposed solution.

Comment: You can check for yourself that the two purported eigenvectors are incorrect. For instance, $Av_i=(1+5i,y+i)^T$, but $(4+i)v_i=(3+5i,8+2i)^T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_2$ being free implies that it is arbitrary. It should have  been $2+2i=x_1$ though.

If $x_1=(1+i)$, then you are correct, and we can deduce that $x_2=1$.